# $\int^0_{-\infty}ze^{2z}dz$ I am stuck

Tags: calculus

I am really trying to solve this problem but I am not following the the solution book. I have used integration by parts.

Yet at that point I become stuck. Help me understand.

Is "Z" considered a constant?

Can I move it outside the indefinite integral? Am I on the right track?

It seems as if I am repeating the same sequence.  [image]

Comment: You need integral $\int v\;du$, right?

Comment: I already did that. Can you see?

Comment: Nope, I see only  $\int u\;dv$ twice.

Comment: Okay maybe thats my problem. Maybe I should take a rest.

Comment: First off, why is there a $dx$? Second, your mistake comes in on the second line. There shouldn't be a $z$ and there should be a $1/2$ in the integral. Third, you need to evaluate the first term in the second line at the bounds (it should go to zero).

Comment: Isnt' it $uv-$$\int\ dv\ u$? However, you are correct the integral is wrong.

Answer (score 6):

\begin{align}
\int z e^{2z}\,dz &= \frac{z e^{2z}}{2}-\int \frac{1}{2}e^{2z}\,dz\\
&=\frac{z e^{2z}}{2}-\frac{1}{4}e^{2z}+C\\
\int_{-\infty}^0 z e^{2z}\,dz &=\lim_{b\to -\infty} \left.\frac{z e^{2z}}{2}-\frac{1}{4}e^{2z}\right|_b^0\\
&=-\frac{1}{4}-\lim_{b\to -\infty}\left(\frac{b e^{2b}}{2}-\frac{1}{4}e^{2b}
\right)\\
&=-\frac{1}{4}-0=-\frac{1}{4}
\end{align}

Comment: Your answer is incorrect. This integral has bounds.

Comment: You made an error before you got the chance to evaluate the bounds. This is the indefinite integral, which is what you had trouble finding.

Comment: I fixed it anyways.

Answer (score 0):

\begin{align}
& \int_{-\infty}^0 z \Big(e^{2z}\,dz\Big) = \overbrace{\int z\,dv = zv - \int v\,dz}^\text{integration by parts} = z\frac 1 2 e^{2z} - \int\frac 1 2 e^{2z}\,dz \\[12pt]
= {} & \left. \frac{ze^{2z}} 2 - \frac {e^{2z}} 4 \right|_{-\infty}^0 = \left( 0 - \frac 1 4 \right) - \lim_{z\to-\infty} \left( \frac{ze^{2z}} 2 - \frac {e^{2z}} 4 \right)
\end{align}

The limit of the first term after $\text{“}\lim\limits_{z\to-\infty}\text{''}$ can be seen to be $0$ via L'Hopital's rule.  The second is easily seen to be $0$.